# Design, cleanup, recycling tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There are 3 "design" tags:

- [design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/design) x 75
- [web-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-design) x 26
- [graphic-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design) x 20

The problem is that according to the [design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/design) tag wiki, it already covers [web-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/web-design) and [graphic-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design):

> Questions relating to software used for **graphic design**, **web design**,
>   computer-aided design, et cetera.

---

What about [cleanup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cleanup) and [disk-cleanup](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk-cleanup)? Should we merge these?

---

<s>Also, can we merge and synonymize [recycle](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recycle) & [recycling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recycling)?</s>

Comment: I'm also against merging web-design and graphic-design into "design". Rather go through that and disambiguate.

Comment: @slhck Umm, okay. there's also `[recycle-bin]`, by the way.

Comment: Not all `[cleanup]` questions are about disk cleanup (e.g. registry, physically cleaning something, etc.). So we'd have to disambiguate that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the [design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/design) tag is rife with requests for programs to fit a personal need, or to find a list of programs the user is asking.

These should instead be closed and/or deleted where you have the necessary votes to.

For those that should be left open, you'll just need to retag those properly to either

- graphic-design
- web-design
- computer-architecture

And [design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/design) will die away normally. Don't just remove this tag as it'll be harder to spot which ones we should just close and delete.

Answer (score 1):

I removed [recycle](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recycle) and created a tag wiki for [recycling](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recycling), [recycle-bin](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recycle-bin) and [trash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/trash) in the meantime.