# Vampyric tags: [design] won't die

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/design) didn't [die like](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6103/74026) we [wanted it to](https://meta.superuser.com/a/6103/74026).

The answer to life, the universe, and everything may be among the questions tagged with it, but these still cover such a broad swath of computery experience that an entirely new computer will need to be built, a computer which integrates living beings into its computational matrix.

Or we could just ask the Vogons to run a hyper-space bypass through the tag. That would work too.

Comment: I know trivial edits are frowned upon, but I *had* to remove that errant 'r'; hope you don't mind!

Comment: Was the form signed in triplicate and placed on display in the local planning department in Alpha Centauri? If so, there's nothing I can say against the edit.

Comment: Wouldn't dream of editing without the form! You can check for yourself; but watch out, there's a big cat there, might be a lynx or a leopard or something...

Comment: There were only a handful left, mostly needing to be closed. The tag should be dead now.

Comment: We should stop re[design]ing this tag.